# Comments in angularjs expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, comments

I have some HTML tags which have ng-clicks and ng-ifs. Inside the respective expressions, I make function calls and pass in parameters, some of which are literals (mostly just true or false). So I would like to add a comment as to what a literal means, but angular doesn't seem to be able to parse this correctly. (I realize passing literals is not the brightest idea but I would nevertheless like to know the answer)

```
<button class='someclass' ng-click='somefunction(val1, val2, true /* explanation for literal */)' > </button>
```

How do I add comments in angular expressions?

Comment: If you need to explain at literal like that, it's probably not the best code. If you really need to provide comments. I'd just use html comments

Comment: why not use object instead of independent params: `someFunction({val1: val1, val2: val2, flag: true})`

Comment: The workaround I went with is to put the complex `someFunction(...)` call inside a function in my JavaScript code and just call a wrapper function with a simpler signature from the AngularJS expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, comments are not supported. Parser sees `/` as an mathematical operator (see [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L118)) which expects [primary expression](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L356) after it: e.g. something starting with `(`, or `[`, etc. However there is no valid expression in javascript that can include `*` immediately after `/` character. So parser throws an exception: `Token '*' not a primary expression`.

Answer (score 1):

While the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) doesn't explicitly say that JavaScript comments are not supported.  I would assume they are not.

Angular Expressions are only a subset of some JavaScript (and some added features like filters).

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you pass these comments as separate parameters instead of appending other parameters?
Even though you achieve doing this somehow it would be not very good design.